# How can I translate this Perl5/PCRE to Perl 6 regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, raku

Just to get this out of the way, I *would* use `index`, `substr` or similar, as they are the obvious solution for my specific case but I'm making a `grammar` and so I can only use `regex`. :(

That being said, advice on translating Perl5/PCRE regex to Perl6 regex is good SO content anyways, because Perl 6 is gaining popularity, and its regex engine is very different.

---

[Here's a regex to only match a string which doesn't contain any of a given list of characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108971/4532996) 
([try it here](https://regex101.com/r/yA0kL3/1).)

```
^(?:(?!\/).)*$
^            # assert position at start of string
(?:          # begin a noncapturing group 
   (?!       # negative lookahead: following regex must not match the string
      \/     # literal forward slash
    )        # end negative lookahead
    .        # any character, once
 )*          # the previous noncapturing group, 0..Inf times
 $           # assert position at end of string
```

Obviously, doesn't work in Perl 6 for a number of reasons.

For the reason stated above, I'd like to use this in Perl 6. Here's what I've tried to translate it to, based on <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> ing [the perl6 regex docs](http://doc.perl6.org/language/regexes) for `non capturing` and `negative lookahead`:

```
[ \/ <!before .*> \/ <!after .*> || .? ]*
```

And the breakdown (I think?):

```
[       # begin a noncapturing group which apparently look like a charclass in p6
\/      # a literal forward slash  
<!before .*> # negative lookahead for the immediately preceding regex (literal /)
\/      # a literal /
<!after .*>  # negative lookbehind for the immediately preceding regex
|| .?   # force this to be a noncapturing group, not a charclass
]*      # end noncapturing group and allow it to match 0..Inf times
```

I implement this like `my regex not-in { ... }` and then use it like `/^<not-in>$/`. However, it returns `Nil` for *every* string, which means it isn't working properly.

I haven't been able to find the equivalent of http://regex101.com for Perl 6, so playing around with it isn't as easy as it would be with Perl 5.

How do I translate this to Perl 6?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms I did, but I have no idea what relevance that has on anything

Comment: `/^not-in$/` should be `/^<not-in>$/`.

Comment: @CIAvash Of course it should! I was tired, sorry.

Comment: You might like [`Grammar::Tracer` and `Grammar::Debugger`](https://github.com/jnthn/grammar-debugger) (both available from installing Grammar::Debugger, if you don't have them already). They have been a lot of help when I've debugged my grammars.

Comment: I think it would be better even in Perl 5 if you just reverse your check `"a" !~ m{/}` in Perl 5 and `"a" !~~ m{'/'}` in Perl 6. Though I can imagine a few cases where you would need to know how to write something like you have. `m{^ [^\/]* $}x` would be better though in this particular case.

Comment: @BradGilbert but you can only use regex in a regex compilation class, which I noted at the top of the question. If I could have arbitrary code in the regex, then I'd use `index` or `substr`.

Comment: `m{^ [^\/]* $}x` would still be better

Comment: @BradGilbert Please add your `"a" !~~ m{'/'}` as an answer. @cat If Brad Gilbert will add that as an answer, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms IIRC, [the accepted answer is the one that was most helpful to the asker, not necessarily the right answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) While Brad's answer may be the correct one, because I am restricted to regex yours was in fact most helpful and will likely stay accepted.

Comment: @cat Thanks. That's interesting. I still hope he adds his answer, though. I like his answer better than mine, whether you do or not. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

Regex for matching only strings that lack forward slashes: `/^ <-[ / ]>* $/`

`/` start of regular expression
`^` beginning of string

`<-[` open negative character class (without the `-`, this would be a normal character class)
`/` characters that the class will not match
`]>`  close character class

`*` zero or more "copies" of this class
`$` end of string
`/` end of regular expression

Spaces in Perl 6 regexes are ignored by default.

---

## Full answer

If I understand correctly, you're just trying to match a string that does not contain a forward slash. In that case, just use a negative character class.

A character class containing `a` and `b` would be written thus: `<[ab]>`

A character class containing anything besides `a` or `b` would be written thus: `<-[ab]>`

A character class containing anything besides `/` would be written thus: `<-[ / ]>` and the regex for making sure that no character in a string contained a forward slash would be `/^ <-[ / ]>* $/`.

This code matches when a string lacks a forward slash and doesn't match when it contains a forward slash:

```
say "Match" if "abc/" ~~ /^ <-[ / ]>* $/; # Doesn't match
say "Match" if "abcd" ~~ /^ <-[ / ]>* $/; # Matches
```

---

The preferred way for just checking for the exclusion of one character is to use the `index` function. However, if you want to exclude more than one character, just use the negative character class with all of the characters you don't want to find in the string.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of my question was correct, sorry. I didn't see in the docs this way of defining negative lookahead, but thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The *literal* translation of your original regex `^(?:(?!\/).)*$` to the Perl 6 syntax is:

```
^ [ <!before \/> . ]* $
```

It's simple enough for a direct translation.

- Replace `(?:`...`)` with `[`...`]`
- Replace `(?!`...`)` with `<!before`...`>`
- Assume the `x` modifier by default

Everything else stays the same in this example.

I've tested it with a simple:

```
say "Match" if "ab/c" ~~ /^ [ <!before \/> . ]* $/; # doesn't match
say "Match" if "abc"  ~~ /^ [ <!before \/> . ]* $/; # Match
```

Comment: Slightly more readable, avoiding “leaning toothpick syndrome”: `^ [ <!before '/'> . ]* $`

Answer (score 2):

## Just to get this out of the way

Your question starts with:

> Just to get this out of the way, I would use index, substr or similar, as they are the obvious solution for my specific case but I'm making a grammar and so I can only use regex. :(

Being pedantic, you can do this. In fact you can embed arbitrary code in Perl regexes.

---

A typical Perl 6 example:

```
/ (\d**1..3) <?{ $/ < 256 }> / # match an octet
```

The `\d**1..3` bit matches 1 to 3 decimal digits. The `(...)` parens surrounding that bit tell Perl 6 to store the match in the special variable [$/](http://doc.perl6.org/language/variables#The_%24%2F_Variable).

The `<?{ ... }>` bit is a code assertion. If the code returns true the regex continues. If not, it backtracks or fails.

---

Using `index` etc. (in this case I've picked [`substr-eq`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/substr-eq)) inside a regex is cumbersome and probably insane. But it's doable:

```
say "a/c" ~~ / a <?{ $/.orig.substr-eq: '/', $/.to }> . c /;
say "abc" ~~ / a <?{ $/.orig.substr-eq: '/', $/.to }> . c /
```

displays:

```
｢a/c｣
Nil
```

(Calling `.orig` on a Match object returns the original string that was, or is being, matched against. Calling `.to` returns the index within that original string that's as far as the match got to, or has gotten to so far; `"abc" ~~ / a { say $/.orig, $/.to  } bc /` displays `abc1`.)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something! When I saw this answer in my notifications, I was expecting to be given a going-over for starting my question like that :)

Comment: I don't want to let [Audrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audrey_Tang) down or have [Jackson Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Galaxy) hunt me down. :)

Comment: I was reviewing some old questions of mine and I think I never clicked the links in your comments but those were quite funny, especially the coincidence that *I'm* a trans female free software dev, too, and now Audrey is my idol :)

Comment: :) I'm curious if you've heard of the [-Ofun](http://o-fun.github.io/) compiler flag?

Comment: I mentioned Audrey in my January comment because I'm always thinking of the love and wisdom that underlies her "hug trolls" notion when I write answers to strangers online. (Not that you were trollish, mind, but whatevs.) I mentioned the [adoption of -Ofun as a guiding principle](http://perl6.org/fun/) because it was/is arguably the most important impact she had on Perl 6. If you haven't visited [#perl6](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net/perl6) or [#perl6-dev](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net/perl6-dev) and experienced -Ofun for real, you're missing out... ;)